# JQuery/PHP trigger click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have put together a code in PHP that will show the 10 first parts of an array and if you click "Next" it will show the 10 next parts of the array, and so on. When I manually click on the "Next" button it works perfect. The problem is that I would like to make it go automatic.

And this is what I've written so far:

the jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#hej').click(function() {
        alert('next button clicked');
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#hej').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
});
```

the php

```
<?php
if ($page < $totalPages)
    echo '<a id="hej" href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next</a>&nbsp;';
?>
```

What happends with this code is that it triggers the alert message automatic after 2 seconds, but it wont show the next 10 parts of the array. If I however manually press "Next" it will trigger both the alert message and show the 10 next parts. Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ndrD5/

one way to solve

basically Jquery can't click on the a link, but needs to click on the text of the a link. Get what I am saying ;)

```
$( function() {
$('#hej').click(function() {
alert('next button clicked');
});

setTimeout(function() {
$('#hej span').trigger('click');
}, 2000);

});
```

the php

```
<?php
if ($page < $totalPages)
echo '<a id="hej" href="?page='.($page + 1).'"><span>Next</span></a>&nbsp;';
?>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that actually works while triggering a click on the 'a' element does not. Nice find!

Comment: Where are you incrementing `$page`?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the problem in this case, but what is wrong with your code is that you render multiple anchor elements with the same id - "hey". Instead use e.g. `class="hey"` and selector `$(".hey")`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.trigger('click')`, any attached `click` event handlers are fired, but the href will not be followed for an anchor that doesn't have any child elements.

However, you can use plain JavaScript to trigger the click:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#hej')[0].click();
}, 2000);
```

The `[0]` notation accesses the plain JavaScript DOM element, with no jQuery wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this will work:

```
$('#hej').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('next button clicked');
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

What happens is that when you click on the link manually the browser change to the href path, and this not happens when you trigger, so you have to do this programmatically.

Comment: why would he open a new window ? And the browser does navigate to another page when you trigger a click.

Comment: I forgot that window.open is only for open in a new window, but using window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') works fine and loads in the same page.